# Best way to Troubleshooting Live Tile notifications that stop working

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I'm finding the messages in the event log very cryptic. Searchs return no decent online documentation on what they mean.

For example I have a message:
The app  was successfully activated for the Windwos.BackgroundTasks contract.

Trying to work out what this means. There are others too. My apps currently focus on background tasks and Tile notifications, and trying to troubleshoot them is difficult.

I have one app that schedules the time periodically. (every hour it schedules the next hour) and another app that runs a background task with a 30 second timer continuously. So there should always be tile notifications happening, and yet I still see blank tiles and can't work out why.

Currently the only error I can see is the one saying a tile timed out while visible. This indicates no more scheduled tiles but no hints as to why they just stop.